# Lock form size in Windows Form Designer

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem when working with a form that has a fixed size.

When I resize Visual Studio windows, the form resizes as well, even when being locked. It is a huge inconvinience because I can't get an idea of how my design would end up.
I am working with a fixed size aplication, that has a MDI child form.

I need the form to have FormBorderStyle to None, so I can't set it to something fixed.

[Image of the form with desired size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXuCG.png)

[Image of the form with deformed size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLQIO.png)

Comment: I've not seen that issue before. If I create borderless window in the designer it remains the same size no matter how many times I resize the VS window. Looking at your screenshot shows a lock icon in the top left of the form design surface which suggests that this might be an inherited form. The original form you're inheriting from has probably got a different size to the one you want.

Comment: The parent has the size I want, but it stills resize to whatever the size I have free in my Visual Studio UI.

Comment: I've just tested this and I can't reproduce it. I even set `IsMDIContainer`. Locked and unlocked the form and it remains the same size no matter how often I change the size of VS.

Comment: Pic with deformed form https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLQIO.png.
I think it is a bug. I couldn't find anyone with the same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` properties of the form to the desired size. This makes the from size fixed.

Note, this trick also works for single-line `TextBox` controls, if you want to set the height to a different height than the one automatically determined from the font size.